# Play scala - websocket multi threading

Tags: multithreading, scala, websocket, playframework-2.3

**Aim:**

Add the multi-threading in the web-socket method by using play framework scala language.

**What I did:**

I have created the web-socket in both client/server side by using the play-websocket sample given by play framework.
In the web socket message I have passed base64 image from the client and received it in the server side.

**What I want:**

I have to pass the base64 image to 4 different methods by using multithreading and pass the result message in the web socket response.

Can anyone tell me, is it possible to do this? If yes, can you tell how to implement this? It would be helpful to me.

**Code snippet:**

**index.scala.html:**

```
    <ul>
        <li id="open">
            <a href='#'>Open WebSocket</a>
        </li>
        <li id="sendMsg" class="disabled">
            <a href='#'>Send echo</a>
        </li>
        <li id="file" class="disabled">
            <input type="file" id="picture" />
        </li>
    </ul>

@ws("WS_Prova")
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function() {

        WS_Prova.address = "ws://localhost:9000/ws"

            WS_Prova.on('open', function(e) {
                $('#status').text("WebSocket: opened").addClass('opened');
            })

            WS_Prova.on('message', function(e) {
                $('#message').text("Received: " + JSON.stringify(e.content));
            })

            WS_Prova.on('close', function(e) {
                $('#status').text("WebSocket: closed").addClass('closed');
                $('#message').text("...");

            })
            $('#picture').change(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var reader = new FileReader;
                reader.onloadend = function () {
                    var obj = {
                        "echo" : false,
                        "data" : reader.result
                    }

                    WS_Prova.send(obj);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            })
    });
```

**Application.scala:**

```
  def index = Action {implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.index("Welcome! Let's Play with your brand new websocket!")).withSession(
        ("uuid" -> java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString)
      )
  }

  def ws = 
    WebSocket.async[JsValue] {implicit request => 
    println("ws call initiated");
      actors.ws.Ws.control
  }
}
```

**Ws.scala:**

```
object Ws extends WebSocketManager[Ws]  {
  case class AlertOnlyMe(uuid: String)
}

class Ws extends WSManagerActor {

  import Ws._
  import WSClientMsgs._

  override def operative(implicit request: RequestHeader) = {
    (wsClient) => { 
    case AlertOnlyMe(uuid) =>
      for {
        clientUUID <- request.session.get("uuid")
        if (clientUUID.compareTo(uuid) == 0)
      } {
        wsClient ! JsToClient(Json.obj(
              "status" -> true,
          "message" -> "success"
            ))
      }
    case JsFromClient(something) =>
      ((something\"echo").asOpt[Boolean]) match {
        case Some(true) =>
          wsClient ! AlertOnlyMe(request.session.get("uuid").getOrElse(""))
        case _ => 
          println((something\"data"))
          var img = something\"data";
          fn1(img.toString());
          fn2(img.toString());
          fn3(img.toString());
          fn4(img.toString());
          self ! JsToClient(Json.obj("broadcast" -> (something\"data")))
      }
  }
  }

  def fn1(img: String) {

  }

  def fn2(img: String) {

  }

  def fn3(img: String) {

  }

  def fn4(img: String) {

  }

}
```

Comment: show some code, in order to get some idea

Comment: @BhargavModi I have added the code snippet.